# is it Possible to use JSON in XNA

Tags: json, xna

0 and i tried to fetch the outside content from XML.But I'm not succeed with that operation. so now I'm searching the another one DB that must replace the XML.I have some idea to use JSON in xna.

Is it possible to use JSON in XNA.Please answer my post.
thanks in advance
Bharathi.G

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` within your application.

To deserialize the JSON input

```
DataContractJsonSerializer deserialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(object));
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonInput));
var obj = deserialize.ReadObject(stream) as object;
stream.Close();
```

And to write some JSON:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, new object()
    {
        // Some data
    });

    json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

I'm using `object` purely for code example, I know that it may cause issues when writing it, but I would assume that you'll be writing to your own object definitions.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of JSON libraries available for use with C# (assuming you're using that) plus for pretty much every other language you could want to use parse it in - [see the list here](http://json.org/).

For future reference, it pays to do some research before asking a question!